# Fastest way to capture from webcams linux

Tags: linux, opencv, video, ffmpeg, webcam

I am capturing images from **UVC** web cam */dev/video0* and convert them to jpeg and send them to my OCR server using Linux (Intel Edison - Yocto linux to be exact)

Currently I am using

> ffmpeg

as my capturing software. This is the command I use to capture the image.

```
./ffmpeg -s 640x640 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vframes 1 image.jpeg;
```

This command takes around 2 seconds to complete which is bad for me to implement realtime OCR.

Is there a fast method to capture from my UVC webcam? Is there a way to keep the video device open always and grab a frame faster. Uncompressed images may not be an option because Im sending the photo using WIFI

I have tried different image capturing softwares like **fswebcam** and **MPlayer** ( [Found here](http://www.netinstructions.com/automating-picture-capture-using-webcams-on-linuxubuntu/) ) but the time is not improved.

Comment: Maybe this works for you as well. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23953/webcam-capture-into-mp4-or-mov-ffmpeg-is-very-slow-at-this

Comment: @cagatayodabasi Thank you very much. I tried the method discussed there. Intel Edison's yocto linux do not have **streamer** and I found no way to install such a package